# der Unterschied zwischen: "momentan", "gerade", "im Moment", "jetzt", "derzeit", "zurzeit"

Tags: difference, vocabulary, adverb

Die Frage ist:
Ich habe immer Probleme damit, die Adverbien "momentan", "gerade", "im Moment", "jetzt", "derzeit" und "zurzeit" zu unterscheiden. Sind sie synonym und austauschbar oder gibt es Unterschiede?

Comment: I reworded the question for clarity (imho). Please revert or revise if I changed what you ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zunächst: im Wesentlichen sind diese Wörter (bzw. Wendungen, im Falle von "im Moment") synonym und austauschbar.

Unterschiede gibt es höchstens in der Konnotation, also "mitschwingenden" Nebenbedeutungen. "Jetzt" kann auch für längere Zeitabschnitte Verwendung finden, während "im Moment" oder "derzeit" meinem Dafürhalten nach kürzere betrachtete Intervalle favorisiert: "*Im Moment* (*derzeit*) sind alle Leitungen besetzt", aber "wir leben in der *Jetzt*zeit". Dieselbe am Telephon abzuwarten hätte wenigstens ich keine Geduld, während mich "*im Moment*" nicht zum sofortigen Aufgeben (und Auflegen) veranlaßt.